# Install csrutil or new recovery partion on High Sierra volume?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, sip

My High Sierra installation did not come with a recovery partition, only internet recovery so I don't have csrutil. It's not in usr/bin, or the base install volume either like many have suggested, Single User Mode does not provide a csrutil either.

I have looked through the stack threads on the issue, and can't find a single solution other than upgrading or reinstalling, neither are an option for me currently. I do not have access to a High Sierra version of cocoadialog (v3.0.0beta7/v2.3.7) so I can't use recover partition installer app either.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to disable SIP at this point?

Comment: I’ve edited this to be one question. If you want to ask the other one, just make a new Q and link here if it helps tie them together.

Comment: @bmike thank you, but your edit violated the integrity of the question itself. Please be more careful when editing other peoples topics. I have updated this to be one question while maintaining the integrity of the question.

Comment: Please edit it back to your intent, just make sure there is one question. I’ll leave your question closed next time so you or someone else can edit if that’s better. Most importantly, thank you for letting me know I missed the mark with the edit. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [rEFInd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/) to your hidden EFI volume. You then can restart the Mac, hold down the option key to invoke the Startup Manager, select rEFInd and instruct rEFInd to enable/disable SIP.

Actually, this is the fastest way to disable SIP because you an also instruct rEFInd to immediately boot macOS after disabling SIP.

Since you currently can not disable SIP, you will have to install rEFInd by not following the installation instructions. For example, to install to the internal drive EFI volume, you would enter the following commands.

> Note: The commands below may overwrite boot files if you already have Windows or Linux installed on your Mac.

```
cd ~/Downloads/refind-bin-0.11.4/
./refind-install --usedefault /dev/disk0s1
```

You can also create a USB flash drive with rEFInd instead of installing to your internal drive.

You may need to add the following lines to the bottom of the `refind.conf` file.

```
csr_values 10,77
showtools csr_rotate, shell, gdisk, memtest, mok_tool, apple_recovery, windows_recovery, about, hidden_tags, reboot, exit, firmware, fwupdate
```

Comment: Thank you this ends a year of headache for me!